# How to speed up my code by openmp with multi for loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Now, l am trying to accelerate the calculation of center of mass in different ROI areas.Her is my original code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "omp.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

#define File_SubAperture        "SubAperture.txt"
#define Row_Subapaerture             750

Mat src;
Mat src_gray;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int thresh = 0;
int max_thresh = 255;
Mat ROI;
int nn = 0;
float subApX[751] = { 0 };
float subApY[751] = { 0 };
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;
float k = 0.0;
float f = 0.0;
int main() 
{   
    clock_t startTime, endTime;
    int     SubAperture[Row_Subapaerture][Col_Subaperture];
    

    double data1, data2, data3, data4;
    int i;
    
    Rect rect_subaperture[Row_Subapaerture];
    FILE * fp_SubAperture;
    FILE* px;
    px = fopen("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\AO acceleration\\center-coordinates-x.txt", "w+");
    FILE* py;
    py=fopen("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\AO acceleration\\center-coordinates-y.txt", "w+");




    //---read file Sub-aperture.txt---*
    fp_SubAperture = fopen(File_SubAperture, "r");
    if (fp_SubAperture == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open the file " File_SubAperture);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; fscanf(fp_SubAperture, "%lf%lf%lf%lf", &data1, &data2, &data3, &data4) != EOF; ++i)
    {
        SubAperture[i][0] = (int)data1;
        SubAperture[i][1] = (int)data2;
        SubAperture[i][2] = (int)data3;
        SubAperture[i][3] = (int)data4;
    }

    fclose(fp_SubAperture);

    //read image
    float sumval = 0.0;
    MatIterator_<uchar> it, end;
    src = imread("WFS_29x29-circle.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    //imshow("gray image", src_gray);




    //calculate the ROI area in advance
    for (i = 0; i < 749; i++) 
    {
        rect_subaperture[i].x = SubAperture[i][0];
        rect_subaperture[i].y = SubAperture[i][1];
        //rect_subaperture[i].width = SubAperture[i][2] - SubAperture[i][0];
        //rect_subaperture[i].height = SubAperture[i][3] - SubAperture[i][1];
        rect_subaperture[i].width = 4;
        rect_subaperture[i].height = 4;
    }
    
    
    startTime = clock();// time start
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel private(ROI,it,i,k,f ) firstprivate(sumval,x,y) shared(src_gray,subApX,subApY,rect_subaperture)
#pragma omp for nowait schedule(guided) collapse(2)
 for(i=0; i<749;i++)
 {
     ROI = src_gray(rect_subaperture[i]);

     for (it = ROI.begin<uchar>(), end = ROI.end<uchar>(); it != end; it++)
     {
         ((*it) > thresh) ? sumval += (*it) : NULL;
        // printf("sum = %f\n", sumval);
     }
 
     for (int k = 0; k < ROI.cols; k++)
     {
         for (int f = 0; f < ROI.rows; f++)
         {
             float S = ROI.at<uchar>(f, k);
             if (S < thresh)
                 S = 0;
            
                 x += (k * S) / sumval;
                 y += (f * S) / sumval;
         }
     }
           subApX[i]= x + SubAperture[i][0];
         subApY[i]= y + SubAperture[i][1];
        
        
         fprintf(px, "\n%f", subApX[i]);
         fprintf(py, "\n%f", subApY[i]); 
}
     endTime = clock();
     printf("time = %f\n", (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
     return 0;

}
```

As you see, I must use multi for loops to finish the calculation. However, the whole code will stuck without any errors, only 50% of calculation is finished, the rest of them can't be calculated.
Anyone knows what's the problems I met? and how to speed up my code. The goal of this code is to calculate the center of mass in different ROI ares of one image. The coordinates will be saved as .TXT files and code will calculate the time needed.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The data dependencies cannot be determined at the moment. End of the code is missing and you have some shared variables that cannot be found in the code at all.

Comment: All of your loops calculate values which depend on the previous loop.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Laci - FYI, if you type this: `[mcve]` , it will expand into a link to _what_ a minimum reproducible example means. :)

Comment: Deleted the `C` tag from this question.

Comment: @ryyker thanks, I did not know that, are there more 'secret codes' like `[mcve]`?

Comment: I could not find a list - But [did find this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: I have [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Note that `collapse(2)` cannot be used here. Moreover, what do you plan to do with `x` and `y`? They cannot be safely used outside the parallel region because of the `firstprivate`. You probably need to use a *parallel reduction*.

Comment: Sorry for uncompleted code, l am uploading the whole code immadiately

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Thank you for your advice, l want to transport x and y to different array and saved as .txt file. l have tried parallel reduction : reduction(+:x,y). however， the whole code will stuck and only part of data is saved in txt file. At the time , l tried to start openmp from inner for loop:for (int k = 0; k < ROI.cols; k++), unfortunately the whole process cost much more time....

Comment: The problem is that in your code `x`,`y` and `sumval` depend on prevoius loops (`i` values). So, if you would like to parallelize it, you have to change the algoritm first (if possible).

Comment: `clock()` does not measure the wall clock time and so must not be used to measure it. Beside this, the code is much more complete which is good but we cannot reproduce it because we input data are missing. Generating random data or providing data would help to reproduce the problem. Finally, `sumval` can theoretically be null regarding the input data. This means a division by zero is possible which is generally a problem (it can cause a floating-point exceptions resulting in a crash).

Comment: Thank you @Laci, l agree with your comment, however, my goal is to calculate center of mass of different ROI area, l need the outer for loop(value of i) to read ROI position data. It's too difficult to change the whole structure of this code,

Comment: Thank you @JérômeRichard, l have considered your suggestion before,  the value of sumval can't be null( l used printf to check them before ). now, the whole code can be run normally without openmp, but it will stuck with openmp. l can provide the necessary data for reproducing.